# JSON deserialization issue with PUT request to Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to perform an update on a resource using WebAPI

I have a controller which performs the Operation

**AdminController class**

```
[HttpPut]
        [Route("newprofile")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Update(AdminAction adminAction)
        {
            if (_adminManager.ApproveUser(adminAction))
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

**Resource**

```
public class AdminAction : BaseResource
  {
    public bool Approve { get; set; }

    public bool Delete { get; set; }

    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public Language eLanguage { get; set; }
  }
```

**Ajax code**

```
activate: function (e) {

        var email = this.model.get('Email');

        var adminAction = {
            "Approve": true,
            "Delete": false,
            "EmailId": email,
            "Language": $("#ddlMotherTongue").val()
        }

        var url = kf.Settings.apiUrl() + '/admin/newprofile';

        $.ajax(url, {
            type: "put",
            data: JSON.stringify(adminAction),
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('Profile approved');
                $("table tr td").filter(function() {
                    return $(this).text().trim() == email;
                }).parent('tr').css({'border': '1px solid green', 'border-left': 'none', 'border-right': 'none','color':'green'});
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (jqXHR.status == 400) {
                    var errorJson = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                    if (errorJson.hasOwnProperty("Errors")) {
                        switch (errorJson.Errors[0].ErrorType) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            async: true
        });
        return false;
    },
```

**Fiddler**

URL: `http://lapi.x.com/admin/newprofile`

**Request Headers**

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization: Token dd39c761-3060-498b-9393-92b12cace238
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 76
Content-Type: application/json
Host: lapi.x.com
Origin: http://x.com
Referer: http://x.com/
```

**Body**

```
{"Approve":true,"Delete":false,"EmailId":"ttt@gnote.com","Language":"Hindi"}
```

When I execute the PUT Operation(Fiddler and Code) the admin object received in the put method(Code behind) has all the types in the object set to default values, i.e the passed values are not deserialized.

Any ideas about what I could have done to the JSON, that the server doesn't like it?

Comment: Try adding `[DataMember]` on one of the members and also `[DataContract]` on the class `AdminAction`. Also which WebAPI you're using 1 or 2 ? Are you using Json.NET or DataContractJsonSerializer ?

Comment: I migrated my project from OpenRasta to WebApi, this Api was working in OpenRasta so I had ignored these attributes my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using `DataContractJsonSerializer` you should have added the relevant attributes.

Class Attribute:

```
[DataContract]
```

Method Attribute:

```
[DataMember]
```